# Select specific fields from entity and it relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have many entities with it relations and due to optimize REST calls to select only this fields that I need actually also with entities relations.
So, I have entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="document_types")
 */
class DocumentType
{
    use RestDefaultsTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $symbol;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $description;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $canBeGenerated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $inEmployer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $inWorker;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $inAll;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $isAnnex;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     *
     *
     */
    private $isAttachment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DocumentType", inversedBy="childDocuments")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $parentDocument;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DocumentType", mappedBy="parentDocument")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     *
     */
    private $childDocuments;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $annexNumberStart;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProfessionGroup", inversedBy="documentTypes")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $professionGroup;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $isNumbering;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $employmentGroup = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $canNumberBeSuggested = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"main-document-type"})
     */
    private $canBeEdited = false;
}
```

And in entity repository i want to do something like this:

```
public function getDocuments( $filterData )
    {

        $select = [
            //          'id'                   => 'id',
            'slug'                 => 'slug',
            'name'                 => 'name',
            'isAnnex'              => 'is_annex',
            'canNumberBeSuggested' => 'can_number_be_suggested',
            'canBeEdited'          => 'can_be_edited',
        ];

        $childDocumentsSelect = [
            'id' => 'id',
            'name'                 => 'name',
        ];

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'document' )
                   ->where( 'document.canBeGenerated = 1' )
        ;

        $qb->select( 'document.id AS id' );
        foreach ( $select as $selectField => $selectValue )
        {
            $qb->addSelect( sprintf( 'document.%s AS %s', $selectField, $selectValue ) );
        }

        $qb->join( 'document.childDocuments', 'childDocuments' );
        foreach ( $childDocumentsSelect as $selectField => $selectValue )
        {
            $qb->addSelect( sprintf( 'childDocuments.%s AS %s', $selectField, $selectValue ) );
        }


        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

with in results I want to recieve base fields from `$select` array and an array of child documents with selected fields in `$childDocumentsSelect` in this example only `id` and `name`

Is even possible? Sometimes my entities have 3 associations sometimes none. At this moment  I'm using serializer but want to optimalize this

Answer (score 0):

Try my example, I think this is what you need.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder( 'document' );
$qb->select([
    'document.slug',
    'document.name',
    'document.isAnnex',
    'document.canNumberBeSuggested',
    'document.canBeEdited',
    'childDocument.id',
    'childDocument.name'
])
->leftJoin('documnet.childDocuments', 'childDocument')
->where('document.canBeGenerated = 1');

$queryResult = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

$items = [];
foreach($queryResult as $item) {
    $id = $item['id'];

    if (!isset($items[$id])) {
        $items[$id]['id'] = $id;
    }

    $items[$id]['child'][] = [
        'slug' => $item['name']
    ];
}


var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I'am afraid I pasted wrong entity. It should be DocumentType and in entity repository I want to get all ```childDocuments``` associated to entity. I tried your solution but it would return only 1 results. All I want is array of associated entities with selected fields

Comment: @bad_programmer
Replace then join with leftJoin, this should help. I updated the example.

Comment: That's almost it. Results returns me new object for each relation. What I want to have is parent object with array of child objects inside

Comment: I get array of object like this: https://imgur.com/a/RFiodH8. You can see that ```id```, ```slug```, ```name```, ```can_number_be_suggested```, ```can_be_edited``` are the same in two objects but ```child_documents_id``` are diffrent. These 2 diffrent props I want to add in parent object as array

Comment: @bad_programmer 
Collect the necessary array from the received data. update example code